# Angular 2 throws error : Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)

Tags: angular

> zone.js:355Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("

Comment: Please post the html that causes this error

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to use curly brackets, try using this syntax

```
{{ '{' }} System {{'}'}
```

which is equivalent to

```
 { System }
```